# JPQL Many to Many with in Clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm wondering if there is a way to convert my native query to a JPQL query.

The query

```
public interface GraphJobRepository extends JpaRepository<GraphJob, Long> {

    @Query(value = "Select * From graph_job where id in (\n" +
            "    SELECT distinct g.graph_job_id\n" +
            "    FROM graph_job_role g\n" +
            "             INNER JOIN clover_role r ON g.clover_role_id = r.role_id\n" +
            "    WHERE r.role_name in (:roles))",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<GraphJob> findGraphJobsByRoles(@Param("roles") List<String> roles);

}
```

CloverRole

```
@Data
@Entity
public class CloverRole {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String roleName;
}
```

GraphJob

```
@Entity
public class GraphJob {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JoinTable(name = "graph_job_role", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "graph_job_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "clover_role_id")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<CloverRole> roles;

}
```

Nothing I've tried has worked, I'm sure if I were to add the join table entity I could get it to work, but I'm wondering if anybody knows how to do it without actually creating that entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `member of` operator, cross join and `List<String>` as a parameter this way

```
@Query("select distinct j from GraphJob j, CloverRole r where r member of j.roles and r.roleName in(:roleNames)")
List<GraphJob> findGraphJobsByRoleNames(@Param("roleNames") List<String> roleNames);
```

Comment: Looks like I'd still need to do a query against CloverRole to get those results, so I'm not sure this would be a better approach. The list of roles initially comes from the authentication principle.

Comment: You can store all CloverRoles in cache as Map<String, CloverRole> and do List<CloverRole> by code. Another solution is to change CloverRole from entity class to enum.

Comment: Worked perfectly, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is getting rid of the embedded string, you may use [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA) for a pure Java solution:

(no changes in existing code is required)

```java
public interface GraphJobRepository extends JpaRepository<GraphJob, Long>,
                                            EntityManagerSupplier {

    default List<GraphJob> findGraphJobsByRoles(List<String> roles) {

        FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((GraphJob job) -> {

            List<Long> jobIds = subQuery((CloverRole r,
                                       JoinTable<GraphJob, CloverRole> graphJobRole) -> {

                SELECT(graphJobRole.getJoined().getId());
                FROM(graphJobRole).JOIN(r)
                                  .ON(graphJobRole.inverseJoin(r, GraphJob::getRoles));
                WHERE(roles.contains(r.getRoleName()));
            });

            SELECT(job);
            FROM(job);
            WHERE(jobIds.contains(job.getId()));

        });

        return query.createQuery(getEntityManager(), GraphJob.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM graph_job t0
WHERE (t0.id IN (SELECT t2.graph_job_id
FROM graph_job_role t2  INNER JOIN clover_role t1  ON (t2.clover_role_id = t1.role_id)
WHERE (t1.role_name IN ?1 )) )
```

FluentJPA provides first class [JPA Repository integration](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/JPA-Repositories) and supplies a "virtual" [join table](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/JPA-Integration#manytomany).